# Amazon SNS has stopped sending text message to mobile

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, web-deployment, amazon-sns

I have created a simple lambda function that I will later integrate with a bigger application. The function uses SNS API to send text message to the specified number. I configured a test event to see whether the function succeeds. It succeeded; and then after few days it stopped, and is never able to send the text. The Node.js looks okay as well as the test event.

I have deleted and recreated the function many times in diffrerent regions with diffrent phone numbers. Still it is not able to delever the text. Could you please help detect me the issue going on here?

index.js

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  var sns = new AWS.SNS();
  var params = {
    Message : event.message,
    MessageStructure : 'string',
    PhoneNumber : event.number,
    Subject : event.subject
  };

  sns.publish(params, function(err,data){
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
     else console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Test event:

```
{
  "message": "Hello",
  "number": "+46762XXXXXX",
  "subject": "From AWS"
}
```

Log output:

```
START RequestId: f524d981-e076-42a1-a52f-8cf069824675 Version: $LATEST
2020-05-20T12:55:47.825Z    f524d981-e076-42a1-a52f-8cf069824675    INFO    {
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'de11439f-ca97-5573-ba79-14a0e18438fb' },
  MessageId: '4af17199-2da6-519c-9848-26a606b5ec14'
}
END RequestId: f524d981-e076-42a1-a52f-8cf069824675
REPORT RequestId: f524d981-e076-42a1-a52f-8cf069824675  Duration: 811.12 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 82 MB  Init Duration: 348.05 ms
```

UPDATE: Acording to several online forums the issue may be with the account spend limit; increasing the limit, e.g. 50 US dollar, can resume the delivery of text message. However in my case I am unable to save the new change in the preferense details. The error output is:

```
Couldn't set text messaging attributes.
Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: Invalid parameter:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a ticket to raise that limit to by example $50. Then, after the ticket as been resolved, you must set the new value (50) in the account spend limit.

The step by step is right [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-sms-spending-limit-increase/)